# How to create models in context with factory_girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

In my model, I have some context validation:

```
class User  
 validate :permissions, on :admin

 def permissions   
   error.add(:permissions, 'Must be set as admin') unless permissions.include? :admin  
 end
end
```

And usage is straightforward:

```
user.save(context: :admin)
```

The question is: How may I check that validations are run in `admin` context via factory_girl? E.g. `create :user, context: :admin` doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get any error when you create your User object using FactoryGirl? What does exactly not work?

Comment: if i run `create :user` there's no errors. but if i run `create :user, context: :admin` i get undefined method context='`

Comment: Do you have attribute_accessors defined in your model?

Comment: No, wouldn't that be wrong to do that ?

Comment: Try adding `attr_accessor: :permissions` to your model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think factory_girl provides a way to `create` or `save` with that option. However, you can work around it with factory_girl's `build`

```
FactoryGirl.build(:user).save!(context: :admin)
```

or `attributes_for`:

```
User.create!(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user), context: :admin)
```

Comment: Thanks for you idea, was just doing something like that

Answer (score 0):

FactoryBot offers a `to_create` method that can be used like this:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    trait :admin do
      to_create { |instance| instance.save!(context: :admin) }
    end
  end
end
```

Or without the `trait`:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    to_create { |instance| instance.save!(context: :admin) }
  end
end
```

[From the docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-methods-to-persist-objects):

> By default, creating a record will call `save!` on the instance; since
> this may not always be ideal, you can override that behavior by
> defining `to_create` on the factory:

```
factory :different_orm_model do
  to_create { |instance| instance.persist! }
end
```